# Dynamic SQL taking much much longer than the hard-coded equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic piece of SQL. It takes about 4 minutes to run. If I instead take the output of the SQL and run that instead, it takes about 20 seconds. Why the discrepancy? I know it would take some amount of time to build up the SQL in the dynamic version, but I can't imagine it's THAT expensive.

Anyone have any ideas? The two queries should be identical, so I was suspecting it was something weird with query plan caching, but don't really have much of an idea.

**Edit:**
To clarify what I mean by taking the output.

In the dynamic SQL the last line is

```
EXEC sp_executesql @myQuery,
    N'@var1 INT,
    @var2 INT,
    @var2 INT',
    @var1,
    @var2,
    @var3
```

I took the value of myQuery and put it in its own SQL file. That is running at 20 seconds while the dynamic one that uses execute takes 4 minutes.

**Edit 2**
I removed the parameters. I got interesting results. The dynamic SQL statement saw a performance improvement. The hardcoded version saw a huge performance hit. The two are about equal now.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You should add way more information, but if hardcoded is that much faster then you're definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. It's a MASSIVE dynamic SQL statement that I can't share, and would take a long time to obfuscate due to the size.

Comment: When you say you "take the output of the SQL and run that instead", what exactly do you mean?  Are you taking the final SQL statement that is being run on the db server?

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong. I routinely use dynamic SQL to improve performance, by hard-coding values that would otherwise be parameters. I have never had performance degrade, even a tad, from doing this.

Comment: willOEM: In the dynamic version, the last line is EXEC sp_executesql '@myQuery,...(parameters).  I took the value of myQuery and ran that instead.

Comment: @user1652427 - If you expect some help here you've got to start reducing you query to the point when it can be shared but still exhibits the behavior you're describing.  It's very likely that use you progress along such process you may solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Shadow Why the bounty? This question has insufficient information to get a meaningful answer. In fact I'm surprised it wasn't closed. If you have a similar problem, perhaps it would be in everyone's best interests if you can post a better question. The problem lies within whatever is going on inside `@myQuery` ... something we cannot guess.

Comment: @CraigYoung because I had the same problem, and one of the answers solved this problem. Got another answer I still need to test, but one of them will get the bounty. This specific problem can't really be described much better: using "sp_executesql" takes much more time than executing the same SQL directly, e.g. via SSMS. There's no code to share, no "what have you done" to share - just an annoying problem that is answered here. Might not fit Stack Overflow, but it's useful. Period.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I take it then you have no insights on the underlying problem? E.g. First run of DSQL is fast, but others not. Or repeating run with same parameters is fine. Or how parameters might differ/affect things? _The thing is I **do think** this question could be very interesting & useful if it had something concrete to work with. - I'd almost like to offer a bounty to find a better question. :P_

Comment: @CraigYoung well, I *think* I understand what you mean. I can, in theory, edit the question to reflect my specific problem and give more/better code, but that would still be something that can't really be reproduced, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7):

I am going to assume you are using Microsoft SQL Server (you only tagged your question  "sql").

There are some cases where different parameter values can result in a different optimization plan.  Then that optimization plan is cached, and used the next time you execute the query with different parameter values.  But the optimization plan isn't the best plan for the subsequent parameter values.

Here's an article about this problem and some workarounds:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/

So yes -- there are some cases where using a parameterized query can result in poor performance compared to running the same query without parameterization.

We can't know if this applies in your case if you aren't at liberty to post your code.

I respect that you can't do that -- by posting to StackOverflow, [you implicitly license your code and/or words with a Creative Commons license](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).  But it would not be appropriate to share code that is owned by your employer, unless they agree to it.

Comment: OP is having the oppisite problem; query without parameterization running much slower than query with parameterization.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, that is not how I read the OP's described problem.

Comment: Either way parameterization vs not can cause different query plans.  And different query plans will cause different run times.

Answer (score 5):

As Bill Karwin says, this could be a 'parameter sniffing' problem. Try including the line:

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

at the end of your SQL query.

There is an article here explaining what parameter sniffing is: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or later, use the OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN query hint.  Add the following to the end of your dynamic query:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@var1 UNKNOWN, @var2 UNKNOWN, @var3 UNKNOWN))
```

Experiment with changing in or out the three inputs @var1, @var2 and @var3.  Yes, it really can be that expensive if the query optimizer tries to use statistics on something that is truly ad hoc.  If one or more of your variables is fairly predictable optimize those for specific values and optimize the remaining for unknown.  Check out this link for more detail.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/

To be clear, this is likely a parameter sniffing problem as indicated by ninjaPixel above.  `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` can give you better results than recompiling every query because the query optimizer relies on statistics to do its compilation.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to give the bounty to ninjaPixel initially, but this answer is even better.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Add a comment to your dynamic query. 
Put in the comment values of variables @var1, @var2, @var3 and etc.

It will look like:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @myQuery,
    /* var1Value, var2Value, var3Value */    
    N'@var1 INT,
    @var2 INT,
    @var2 INT',
    @var1,
    @var2,
    @var3
```

So, execution plan will recompile for different values only.